# Can I somehow implement bracketed casting between Double and Integer classes in Java?

Tags: java

I know Java doesn't allow direct casting between Integer and Double classes like so:

```
var intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// code that fills intList with Integer entries

var doubleVal = (Double) intList.get(0); // Class Cast exception
```

I also know the reason why and the solution(s) to this.

My question is - is there a way to make this work ? Can I implement something such that when I use `(Double) intList.get(0)` in my code, it actually gives me what I want instead of throwing an exception ?

In C# I would simply override the cast operator to do this and it would work, but sadly Java doesn't allow that.

Comment: `(Double) ((int) intList.get(0))`

Comment: @user16320675 - but that requires that the OP replace the `var` declaration with a declaration with an explicit type.

Comment: Nothing.  Except that the OP is using `var`  And presumably there is a reason for that.   Like ... he/she thinks that `var` is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I somehow implement bracketed casting between Double and Integer classes in Java?

Basically no.   There are no Java tricks that you can use to make a simple `(Double)` cast do what you want to happen here.

---

Your example expression `(Double) intList.get(0)` requires too many conversions for the compiler to be "happy".  It needs to unbox the `Integer` to an `int`, widen it to a `double`, and then box it as a `Double`.  Three conversions.

You have to give it some help.  Here are some of the ways you could help:

```
  (Double) ((int) intList.get(0))
```

The cast to `int` causes the `Integer` to be unboxed.  From there it can be widened to a `double` and then auto-boxed to a `Double`.

```
  (Double) (intList.get(0).doubleValue())
```

This does the `Integer` to `double` via the `doubleValue` call, and then the `(Double)` does the final step.

```
  Double.valueOf(intList.get(0).doubleValue())
```

As above but using an explicit call to do the boxing.

Comment: Sigh, I thought as much. Thanks for the detailed response Stephen.

For the time being, I'm using `Double.parseDouble(intList.get(0).toString())`. Seems to work okay and is easier to read too (for me anyways haha).

Comment: That's not a good solution.  Converting to a string and back are relatively expensive operations.